# getting a registry key and value in C#

Tags: c#

Sorry if this is simple, I haven't coded since college. I'm trying to write a program to view registry entries in Windows 7. I want to check to see if the registry value exists first, then check to see what the value is. If it doesn't exist, I want one message, if it does exist, I want one message reflecting a value of 1, and another reflecting a value of 0. I got the code to work if the registry key doesn't exist, but if I add the key and value it crashes. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Here is my code.

```
using (RegistryKey Key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters"))
if (Key != null)
{
    string val = (string)Key.GetValue("EnableOplocks");
    if (val == null)
    {
        oplockTextBox.Text = "Not Present In Registry";
        oplockTextBox.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    else if (val == "1")
    {
        opslockTextBox.Text = "NO";
        opslockTextBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        oplockTextBox.Text = "YES";
        oplockTextBox.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("");
}
```

Comment: What exception is getting thrown?  It seems like it could be a permissions error

Comment: Crashes with what exeption?  Could it be an `InvalidCastException` from casting the value to a string?

Comment: Sorry, I should have included the exception. Yes, it says InvalidCastException was unhandled. Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the [`EnableOplocks`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/296264/configuring-opportunistic-locking-in-windows) value for that registry key is a `DWORD` value, which will give you an `int` when you use `GetValue()` to retrieve it.  Trying to cast an `int` to a `string` will produce an `InvalidCastException`.

Instead, you should try this:

```
int? val = Key.GetValue("EnableOplocks") as int?;
if (val == null)
{
    // ..
}
else if (val == 1)
{
    // ...
}
```

Or this:

```
object val = Key.GetValue("EnableOplocks");
if (val == null)
{
    // ...
}
else
{
    string strVal = val.ToString();
    if (strVal == "1")
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

In general, please remember to provide *all* of the error information you have.  Saying "it crashes" is not very informative.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, JLRishe. I'll try it and see what happens. Sorry about not including the error information, I know better than that, just been staring at the code for too long and zoned out.

Comment: I went with your first example and that worked perfect! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The registry can hold data-types other than string. What is happening is you are likely getting a `int` returned and that is why you are crashing when you attempt to cast a `int` to a `string`

Get the value back and store it in a `object` and have your debugger break. You should then be able to see what datatype is stored in the object and change your code to make the correct cast.

The other option would be use `.ToString()` instead of casting, you would need to compare the string 1 (like you are now) instead of the value 1. However, I always prefer to just use the correct type instead of turning everything in to strings.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Scott. I'll look into this one as well and report back.

Comment: I would use [JLRishe's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14765823/80274) using the `int?` operator, it will solve your problem the best.

Answer (score 1):

Use follow;

```
string val = Key.GetValue("EnableOplocks").ToString();
```

**EDIT**

```
using (RegistryKey Key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanServer\Parameters"))
if (Key != null)
{
    var val = Key.GetValue("EnableOplocks");
    if (val == null)
    {
        oplockTextBox.Text = "Not Present In Registry";
        oplockTextBox.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    else if (val.ToString() == "1")
    {
        opslockTextBox.Text = "NO";
        opslockTextBox.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        oplockTextBox.Text = "YES";
        oplockTextBox.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("");
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to cast as string? `ToString()` already returns an string.

Comment: Since his variable `val` is a `string` type, we need to assign a sting value for that(That is why use `ToString()`)

Comment: @OscarMederos-I understood the problem with my answer. Its a typo error.

Comment: I tried New Developer's suggestion and it worked when the value was present and was either 1 or 0, but when it was not present (null) it crashed with a NullReferneceException was unhandled error. Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Thank you for everyone's suggestions so far, I really appreciate the help!